# SQL Developer Changing Date format for a specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, date-formatting

I have a set of data,

```
convert(varchar(10), D.LAST_DATE_CTZ, 101),
D.EQUIPMENT_NUMBER,
D.DAYS_REMAINING,
D.LAST_DATE_CTZ,
E.CURRENT_FAC_CODE,
DUE_WINDOW_CTZ,
D.DUE_DATE_CTZ


From MVA_EQUIPMENT_DETAILS E,
MVA_EQUIPMENT_VMRS_DUES D,
MVA_FACILITIES F
where 
E.EQU_ID = D.EQU_EQU_ID
```

I am looking to change the format of the date for the one column ( D.LAST_DATE_CTZ) which shows up as dd-mmm-yyyy and I want to change it to mm-dd-yy

Not sure how I am doing my query wrong. I just want to be able to read the data differently not change anything within the table.

Thanks

Comment: Use `to_char()` - `convert()` is invalid for Oracle

Comment: @Andrew , please try below query again I have modified it.

Comment: It worked! thank you

Answer (score 0):

please try this query and let me know.

```
 SELECT convert(varchar(10), D.LAST_DATE_CTZ, 10),
  D.EQUIPMENT_NUMBER,
  D.DAYS_REMAINING,
  E.CURRENT_FAC_CODE,
  DUE_WINDOW_CTZ,
  D.DUE_DATE_CTZ
From MVA_EQUIPMENT_DETAILS E,
     MVA_EQUIPMENT_VMRS_DUES D,
     MVA_FACILITIES F
where 
  E.EQU_ID = D.EQU_EQU_ID
```

Comment: hello, it is saying invalid statement. does to char? need to be used?